# how to determine if a cell has multiple values and count the number of occurences

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a table as below where i need to count the number of times the type column has more than one value in it.

My logic at the moment is to go through each time and check if the type cell has more than one value in it and place a counter but i am not sure how to code this in Python correctly.

[image]

I tried this method below but i don't think it helps in my case considering that it is also hierarchical:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(pd.DataFrame(data['Country'].str.split(',', expand=True)).values.ravel())
```

Comment: Hi, can you please include some sample output?

Comment: the output i am expecting is: car_type - number of rows with multiple labels and bike_type - number of rows with multiple labels so for car should return 5 and for bike should return 5 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
## df is your data (gives pandas series)
df['type'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(','))).value_counts()

## or convert it to dict
df['type'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(','))).value_counts().to_dict()
```

Comment: thanks, how will it know that i am counting for type of car or type of bike since it is hierarchical? can i include df['car','type'].apply?

Comment: yes, you can do that. make sure the df is multiindex hierarchical.

Comment: i missed to mention that these labels are represented in the form of tuples like - (medium, purple) so it's now generating an error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'. so how do I split and count when it is in this format?

Comment: @Py_Mel just made a tiny change in the answer to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Using `get_dummies` with `sum`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'type':['big,green','big','small,red']})
df.type.str.get_dummies(sep=',').sum(1)
Out[382]: 
0    2
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'type':['big,green','big','small,red']})
for i in df['type']:    print(len(i.split(',')))
```

Comment: thanks. i will try this but just to confirm, will the type have only those 3 values then to compare? also my table is hierarchical with car and bike so how do I differentiate for the two?

Comment: In this case, you can make two "for" loopings. One for the car another for the bike. To help you better, I must see more of your DataFrame structure.